# Running a bash shell from python: properly detecting when the prompt returns

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I am writing a program that does the submission and bookkeeping of tasks to an external computing grid. In order to submit such a task, I need to setup the correct environment (read: execute a bash setup script) and then execute the bash command to submit the task. To complicate the matter, the task being submitted can rely on customized code which needs to be compiled locally in order to be tested, before being uploaded to grid. The compilation takes a certain amount of time, and the compiler produces output to the bash shell at unpredictable and variable intervals. You'll see how this is relevant by looking at my attempt to implement a solution:

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------
def shell_command(poll, shell, command):
    """
    Sends a command to the shell
    """
    output = ''

    ## Send command
    shell.stdin.write(command + '\n')
    shell.stdin.flush()

    ## Wait for output
    while poll.poll(500):
        result = shell.stdout.readline()
        ## Print and record output
        print result,
        output += result

    return output

## ---------------------------------------------------------
def start_shell():
    """
    Starts the shell associated to this job
    """
    ## Start the shell
    shell = subprocess.Popen(['bash'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    ## Associate poll to shell
    poll = select.poll()
    poll.register(shell.stdout.fileno(), select.POLLIN)

    ## Setup environment
    shell_command(poll, shell, 'export ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=/path/to/stuff')
    shell_command(poll, shell, 'source $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE/setup.sh')

    return poll, shell

## Main code
poll, shell = start_shell()
shell_command(poll, shell, 'compile local code')

[...] do some testing on the compiled code [...]

shell_command(poll, shell, 'submit task on the grid')
```

So the issue I encounter is that the correct execution of the code depends on the timeout I give to poll.poll(timeout). I can always give a ridiculously long timeout, and then the code never fails, but it takes a correspondingly long time before the code finishes. With a short timeout, the execution of the code will be interrupted as soon as the compiler provides no output for longer than timeout.

I tried using subprocess.Popen.communicate(), but it doesn't seem to allow me to pass multiple commands to the same shell (and allow me to keep the shell alive for later), and I don't want to have to setup the environment every time I need to issue a new command.

It seems to me that select.poll can only detect when output is produced on stdout, but what I would really like to do is detect the prompt return. Is this possible in this context? Any other ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect may be useful for you

Comment: I would prefer to avoid external dependencies, but pexpect sounds indeed pretty spot on, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out pexpect was present in the environment in which I wish my code to run, so I tried it but with minimal success, and it would take too long to explain why. I'm satisfied for the moment with modifying the shell_command function like this:

```
## ---------------------------------------------------------
def shell_command(poll, shell, command):
    """
    Sends a command to the shell
    """
    output = ''

    ## Send command
    shell.stdin.write(command + '; echo awesomeapplesauce\n')
    shell.stdin.flush()

    ## Wait for end of process, signaled by awesomeapplesauce
    print 'executing \'{0}\''.format(command)
    while True:
        if poll.poll(500):
            result = shell.stdout.readline()
            output += result
            if 'awesomeapplesauce' in result: break
            print result,

    return output
```

It's a bit of a hack I guess, but it's sufficiently robust for my purposes. In words, at the end of every command sent to the shell, chain an echo command that echoes a unique string, and then wait for that string to be printed out to terminate the polling loop and move on. If anyone has a more fundamental way of spotting a prompt return, I would still be delighted to learn about it!

Comment: why cannot you use the return code?  If submission succeeds, return code should be 0, non-zero otherwise.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, because I start a shell using 'bash'. Subprocess is waiting for the return code of 'bash', and it completely unaware of what happens within it.

Comment: And yes, I do want to create a fresh new shell. I may have several shells alive with different setups in the most general case.

Answer (score 0):

Does looking at the return code like this work?

```
from subprocess import call
out = open('/tmp/out.log', 'w')
err = open('/tmp/err.log', 'w')
ret = call('export FOO=foobar;echo $FOO', stdout=log, stderr=err, shell=True)
print ret
ret = call('test -e /tmp/whoosh', stdout=log, stderr=err, shell=True)
print ret
```

Comment: subprocess.call does not keep a shell alive. In your code, add `call('echo $FOO', stdout=log, stderr=err, shell=True)`, and then look at the output. You'll find out that FOO is now empty. Not very convenient when the shell commands you are sending require Athena (and its dozens of environment variables) to be setup....